# MySQL if one or more of the rows were not updated because they do not exist, insert them [ WHERE IN ]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a category system for my website, and I need to be able to insert a category into its table if it was not updated due to its non-existence.

I have the first part that updates all categories defined in the WHERE IN statement here:

```
UPDATE `cat` SET `posts` = posts +1 WHERE cat IN ('category1', 'category2', 'idonotexist1', 'idonotexist2')
```

How would I have SQL efficiently insert into the table any categories which could not be updated because they did not exist?

Just to be specific, I know how to do this when you are only doing one UPDATE, but with WHERE IN, its a bit more complicated for me. I'm looking for something that will insert `idonotexit1` and `idonotexist2` into the table, since it does not exist.

I will provide all information requested.

Comment: How about

INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Yes, but how do I check if any of the attempted insert rows already exist?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that you have a unique index in your `cat` table:

```sql
alter table cat add unique index idx_cat(cat);
```

After that, for each category in your list, you can do something like:

```sql
insert into cat values('category1', 1)
on duplicate key update posts = posts + 1;
```